# Signal becomes undefined when used in process

Tags: vhdl

I'm having problems with this VHDL code where the value of new_state isn't being transferred onto the signal state_cnt and is instead becoming undefined.

What do I need to change in-order to get this to work?

```
Library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity test_controller is
  port (
    clk, reset, wr : in std_logic;
    wr_data : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    op_a, op_b, op_c : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
  ); 
end test_controller;
architecture rtl of test_controller is

signal busy : std_logic := '0';
signal state_cnt : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := "00";

begin

   input_proc : process(wr)
     variable new_state : integer; 
     begin
        if rising_edge(wr) then
          if busy = '0' then
            if state_cnt = "00" then
              op_a <= wr_data;
              new_state := 1;
            elsif state_cnt = "01" then
              op_b <= wr_data;
              new_state := 2;
            elsif state_cnt = "10" then
              op_c <= wr_data;
              busy <= '1';
              new_state := 0;
            end if;
            state_cnt <= conv_std_logic_vector(new_state,2);
         end if;
        end if;
     end process;
end rtl;
```

Testbench

```
Library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity tb_test_controller is

end tb_test_controller;

architecture exercise of tb_test_controller is

  component test_controller

      port (
            clk, reset, wr : in std_logic;
            wr_data : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        op_a, op_b, op_c : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)

  ); 

  end component;

  signal clk_i :  std_logic;
  signal reset_i : std_logic;
  signal wrdata_i : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal op_a_i : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal op_b_i : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal op_c_i : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal wr_i : std_logic;

  constant CLK_PERIOD : time := 20 ns;
  constant DLY : time := CLK_PERIOD*2;

  begin

    clkmeProc : process
      begin
        clk_i <= '1';
        wait for CLK_PERIOD/2;
        clk_i <= '0';
        wait for CLK_PERIOD/2;
      end process;
    resetmeProc : process
      begin
        wait for DLY;
        reset_i <= '1';
        wait for CLK_PERIOD;
        reset_i <= '0';
        wait;
      end process;
    inputDataProc : process
      begin
        wait on reset_i until reset_i = '0';
        for i in 0 to 10 loop
          wrdata_i <= conv_std_logic_vector(i, 32);
          wr_i <= '1';
          wait for CLK_PERIOD;
          wr_i <= '0';
          wait for CLK_PERIOD;
         end loop;
      end process;     


      DUT : test_controller
      port map
      (
        clk =>clk_i,
        reset => reset_i,
        wr_data => wrdata_i,
        wr => wr_i,
        op_a => op_a_i,
        op_b => op_b_i,
        op_c => op_c_i
      );
    stimProc : process
      begin
        wait;
      end process;

  end exercise;
```

[image: testbench]

Comment: Why the type conversion? Why not make State_Cnt a ranged natural too? What does the non-standard conversion function you're using actually do - does it assume a signed or unsigned integer? Does anything else assign to State_Cnt? If you posted a compilable example instead of a fragment there'd be less guessing and more helping in this comment.

Comment: Where is the entity declaration? Why aren't you displaying the signals that are inputs to the state machine? You have supplied nowhere near enough information to allow this question to be answered.

Comment: Added more information.

Comment: Your test_controller entity's port declaration is missing op_a, op_b and op_c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're code wasn't quite complete missing the mode out port declarations for `op_a`, `op_b` and `op_c` from entity test_controller.

Apparently using a different simulator and after correcting the discrepancy in your code I get a different answer.

You don't have any tags or real clues whose tool you are using. Your waveform doesn't match the (corrected) code you have posted (and VHDL is supposed to be portable).

[image: tb_test_controller.png]

The only thing I see wrong here is that your testbench ought to provide a default value for`wr_i` of '0'. The rising_edge function won't see the transition from 'U' to '1' as a rising edge.

This sort of says you're having tool problems (I trust this VHDL implementation here).

Please provide more information on the tool you're are using and provide waveforms that match your actual code you provide.

In the mean time you might see if Paebbel's change does simulate correctly.

Notice you don't have anything that assigns the value of `busy` back to a '0'.

Answer (score 2):

I transformed your test_controller into a simpler version. It uses one counter and a case statement. No need for variables or type conversions.

```
architecture rtl of test_controller is
  signal busy : std_logic := '0';
  signal state_cnt : UNSIGNED(1 downto 0) := "00";
begin
  input_proc : process(wr) 
  begin
    if rising_edge(wr) then
      if busy = '0' then
        state_cnt <= state_cnt +1;
        case state_cnt is
          when 0 =>      op_a <= wr_data;
          when 1 =>      op_b <= wr_data;
          when 2 =>      op_c <= wr_data;
                                 busy <= '1';
          when others => null;
        end case;
      else
        state_cnt <= (others => '0'); 
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
end rtl;
```